# How to loop over multiple panda dataframes with a for loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to harmonize the column names in all my data frames so that I can concatenate them and create one table. I'm struggling to create a loop over multiple dataframes.  The code does not fail, but it does not work either.  Here is an example of two dataframes and a list that includes the dataframes:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'HHLD_ID':[6,7,8,9,10],
                   'sales':[25,50,25,25,50],
                   'units':[1,2,1,1,2],
                   })

df_test2 = pd.DataFrame({'HHLD_ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'sale':[25,50,25,25,50],
                   'unit':[1,2,1,1,2],
                   })

list_df_export = [df_test,df_test2]
```

Here is what I have tried...

```
for d in list_df_export:
    if 'sale' in d:
        d = d.rename(columns={"sale": "sales",'unit':'units'})
```

Here is what I would like df_test2 to look like...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the "inplace" option can help you:

```
 for d in list_df_export:
    if 'sale' in d:
        d = d.rename(columns={"sale": "sales", 'unit': 'units'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: The inplace allows me to do this in multiple steps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
d = {'sale':'sales','unit':'units'}
pd.concat(i.rename(columns=d) for i in list_df_export)
```

Comment: This is great if I want to make the correction and concatenate it in one step. If I want to correct all of the dataframes with the misspellings and be able to use them afterwards (df_test2 in this case), how would I do this?

Comment: @JonathanHay you mean we don't know in advance the correct spellings? how do we determine what the correct spelling is.?

Comment: Let me clarify, I know the correct spellings for example "sales" and "units" and I know the potential incorrect spellings, but I don't know which dataframes will have the correct or incorrect spellings in advance. Since I want to use the dataframes for more than just concatenating, I was hoping to learn how to loop over multiple dataframes to make update each of the dataframes.

Comment: @JonathanHay in that case this is the way to go. Rename will rename only when the key matches, it wouldnt impact the other columns for which it doesnt find a match. So only the columns having the wrong spellings will be renamed. `[i.rename(columns=d) for i in list_df_export]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df_test2.columns = df_test.columns
```

This will make the columns in df_test2 have the same names as df_test.

Is this what you need?

Comment: This would work if I knew in advance which dataframes will have which column names and if the number of columns was always the same. I'm trying to loop over all dataframes and rename the incorrectly labeled columns.